# how to get refunded transactions details using payflow pro api php

Tags: php, payflowpro

I have integrated Payflow pro payment gateway into my php application and processing payment requests using Payflow as payment gateway.

I need to retrieve transaction history which includes refunds too for specific profile ID.

Below is the code that I am using: ref - (https://github.com/rcastera/Paypal-PayFlow-API-Wrapper-Class).

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/Class.PayFlow.php');

$PayFlowAuth = new PayFlow($Vendor, $Partner, $User, $Password, 'single');
$PayFlowAuth->setTransactionType('R');
$PayFlowAuth->setProfileAction('I');
$PayFlowAuth->setCustomField('ORIGPROFILEID', 'RP0000000XYZ' );
$PayFlowAuth->setCustomField('PAYMENTHISTORY', 'Y' );
$PayFlowAuth->setEnvironment('live');
$PayFlowAuth->processTransaction();

$response = $PayFlowAuth->getResponse();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

I get below response:

```
Array
  (
      [RESULT] => 0
      [RPREF] => RHX51F5D3XYZ
      [PROFILEID] => RP0000000XYZ
      [P_PNREF1] => BK0P6E1C2XYZ
      [P_TRANSTIME1] => 19-Jun-19  04:42 AM
      [P_RESULT1] => 0
      [P_TENDER1] => C
      [P_AMT1] => 30.00
      [P_TRANSTATE1] => 8
      [P_PNREF2] => BK0P6EB8DXYZ
      [P_TRANSTIME2] => 21-Jul-19  04:44 AM
      [P_RESULT2] => 12
      [P_TENDER2] => C
      [P_AMT2] => 30.00
      [P_TRANSTATE2] => 1
      [P_PNREF3] => BR0P6482FXYZ
      [P_TRANSTIME3] => 19-Aug-19  04:52 AM
      [P_RESULT3] => 0
      [P_TENDER3] => C
      [P_AMT3] => 30.00
      [P_TRANSTATE3] => 8
  )
```

However it does not include refunded transaction. When I search in paypal manager, I can see these 3 transactions along with 1 refund transaction too. I tried changing TRXTYPE to C (credit) but it gives the error: Invalid tender

So I am looking for any such parameter change where I can retrieve refunded transaction history or may be any method in payflow pro api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end asked paypal support and they replied.

> unfortunately, there is no API to get refunded transactions. I'll
>   contact our engineers for possible feature request. I apologize for
>   the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.  Credits are issued outside of the profile so they are not tied to it and as a result do not show up when doing a PAYMENTHISTORY call.